# Allowing Chrome DevTools access to /opt

Tags: 20.04, permissions, chromium, opt

I am trying to debug a node program using the Chrome inspector. When I try to add the folder the program is in ( which is in /opt/lampp/htdocs/nodestuff ) to the workspace, I receive a "permission denied" notice.

It's my understanding that changing the permissions of the /opt folder is *A Very Bad Thing* . Any suggestions on the best practices for this situation?

I am using Chromium, which I installed through the Ubuntu Software app.

Comment: Are you using a snap version of Chrome, or a `.deb`-installed version?

Comment: @matigo : I believe it's the snap version, I installed it through the Ubuntu Software app.

Comment: Snap applications are generally sandboxed with limited access to your home directory. As `/opt` is very much outside of `~`, there will be visibility problems. The simplest way to resolve this would be to install the `.deb` version of Chrome or — believe it or not — the `.deb` version of Edge, which is actually pretty decent on Ubuntu and is built on Chromium.